# lookup method from config java

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

What would be the better approach to do invoke method based on config value.

```
List<String> configs = "from config file"

for(string config : configs) {
    if (config.equal("method1")) {
        someObj.method1();
    } else if(config.equal("method21")) {
        someObj2.method21()
    }
}
```

Comment: Better out of which options?

Comment: I just can make a good design decision on this. I'm trying to call individual method based on config value stored in config file. right now i'm just doing to if stmt to check config value matches predefine value in the code. But i think this is bad design since this could be very flaky and not a clear way to change the config value without first looking at the code and see what values are there...

Comment: Where do `someObj` and `someObj2` come from?  How to know which instance to use?

Comment: @AndrewS someOjb# are the predefined classes. and that's the design challenge that i have. Basically my problem is mapping and running a process based on user config either at the load time or runtime.

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke it by reflection:

```
//in the loop
...
Class<?> c = Class.forName("Your class");
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(config, parameterTypes);
method.invoke(obj, params);
```

Comment: Yes, i know you can invoke method using reflection. My question is more of designing the right solution than implementation.